# How config Slim 4 in remote CPanel

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

please a need a help, my application works in localhost but i cannot make work in my cpanel web host.

PHP 8.*
Slim 4.*
The error is a simple statuscode 500.

The app tree:

```
myDomain
└── api
    ├── public
    │   └── index.php
    └── vendor
```

In api lvl a have an htaccess for redirect to public:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

And in public folder i have an htaccess to rewrite de base route:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

My index in public is:

```
<?php
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();

(require __DIR__ . '/../config/router.php')($app);

$app->run();
```

My router file in config folder is:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use Slim\App;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use App\Controllers\{
    AuthController,
};




return function (App $app) {
    $app->get('/', function(Request $request, Response $response){
        $request->getQueryParams();
        $response->getBody()->write("This is the initial route");
        return $response;
    }); 
    $app->group('',function($app){
    
        $app->get('/test', function(Request $request, Response $response){
            $response->getBody()->write("Its workin another route!");
            return $response;
        }); 
        $app->get('/recover-password', function(Request $request, Response $response){
            $response->getBody()->write("Its work!");
            return $response;
        });         
    });

};
```

Comment: Hi there, are you using slim skeleton framework?

Comment: Is `myDomain/` the document root? What URL are you requesting? You need to check your server's error log for the details of the 500 error .

Comment: No, i am not using skeleton,
I dont have log.

I try deploy the get started code and works, so de problem is in public/index.php && config/routes.php relationship.

I try call domain/api, and try call domain/api/public/, i try call direct index.php in these urls, too, and i try change de index to api path, nothing works